# Function mutates byte slice argument

Tags: go, arrays

I have the following code where I have a slice of bytes with the alphabet, I copy this alphabet array in a new variable (cryptkey) and I use a function to shuffle it. The result is that the alphabet and the cryptkey byte slice get shuffled. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    alphabet := []byte("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.")
    cryptkey := alphabet
    fmt.Println(string(alphabet))
    cryptkey = shuffle(cryptkey)
    fmt.Println(string(alphabet))
}

func shuffle(b []byte) []byte {
    l := len(b)
    out := b
    for key := range out {
        dest := rand.Intn(l)
        out[key], out[dest] = out[dest], out[key]
    }
    return out
}
```

Result :

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.
>   miclOfEInzJNvZe.YuVMCdTbXyqtaLwHGjUrABhog xQPWSpKRkDsF

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Cp0yyX6Lrs)!

Comment: The key thing to realize is that []byte is a byte slice, not a byte array. http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals . This means that it can be thought of as a pointer to an underlying array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a copy. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    alphabet := []byte("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.")
    cryptkey := alphabet
    fmt.Println(string(alphabet))
    cryptkey = shuffle(cryptkey)
    fmt.Println(string(alphabet))
}

func shuffle(b []byte) []byte {
    l := len(b)
    out := append([]byte(nil), b...)
    for key := range out {
        dest := rand.Intn(l)
        out[key], out[dest] = out[dest], out[key]
    }
    return out
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.
```